# CoreData List Items, Edit View

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

Need help passing CoreData to another view after its saved to the database. I have a separate view to "Add Items" and the List View shows the items, sorted. With NavigationView I can tap to see each entry, but I want to .onTapGesture overlay a new View with the list items that are editable.
Struggling to figure this out.

Right now this works to see more detail of each list item, but I'd rather have it open a new view with an .onTapGesture but can't figure out how to pass the database item tapped to the new View and set it to edit.

```
NavigationView{
    List {
          ForEach(newItem) { newItems in
               NavigationLink(destination: TapItemView(database: newItems)) {
                   DatabaseRowView(database: newItems)}
          }
     }.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
}
```

?

Comment: CoreData and all ObservableObjects should be wrapped in an ObservedObject wrapper when you want to see changes

Answer (score 0):

An observation: in your code sample--"ForEach(newItem) { newItems in" should be "ForEach(newItems) { newItem in". In other words the collection goes in the ForEach parentheses and the single item precedes the "in". With that, I started with the Xcode-generated project with Core Data for this example (Xcode Version 13.1). Modifications are included in the code below.

```
@State var showEditView = false
@State var tappedItem: Item = Item()
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        tappedItem = item
                        showEditView = true
                    }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showEditView) {
                EditView(item: $tappedItem)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a possible receiving view for the tapped item:

```
struct EditView: View {
@Binding var item: Item
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Date")) {
                DatePicker("Date Selection",
                           selection: $item.timestamp,
                           displayedComponents: [.date]
                )
                .datePickerStyle(.compact)
                .labelsHidden()
            }
        }
    }
}
```